# Decomposition of a square wave with a duty cycle of 40%

Tags: signal-processing

I'm studying the decomposition of a square wave with an amplitude of 500mV and a frequency of 80kHz. With a duty cycle of 50%, I have obtained a negative exponential graph but with a duty cycle of 40%, I've got a very weird result and was wondering if whether what I have done and calculated is correct?[image]

Comment: I'm confused. Is the chart what you actually got using a real signal at 40%, digitized at some sample rate for some period of time and then analyzed with windowing and an FFT? Or is the chart what you calculated, as a theoretical result? And yes, at least *some* parts of that chart look right to me. But I have problems understanding it fully.

Comment: Please provide more details is this 500mV pk-to-pk? and If so is this going from 0V to 500mV or from a negative value to a positive one?

Comment: Erm I obtained this chart after doing all the calculations myself using the fourier coefficients and finding the sum of their values by s²=a²+b²  as well as the square wave is that from 0 to 500mV. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is 40% duty cycle squarewave

[image]

Comment: what shape is the form of the spectrum suppose to resemble? Is it more towards a cardinal sine?